# HTML slider won't hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide an html slider and submit button with jquery when the submit button is clicked. Unfortunately, my code isn't working and the slider and submit button are only momentarily hidden before they come back. I would really appreciate and help!

```
    <form>
        <input id="bet" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1"   onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
        <input id="submit_bet" type="submit" value="Submit Bet!"/>
    </form>

    <span id="range">0</span>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showValue(newValue)
    {
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
    }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submit_bet").click(function() {
                $("#bet").hide();
                $("#submit_bet").hide();
                $("range").hide();
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I understand your design...

If you just want to hide slider and submit button when you clicked, you can try:

```
<input id="submit_bet" type="button" value="Submit Bet!"/>
```

When you use `type="submit"` button, it will send form and refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,you had forgotten the "#" which selects the id of range span element,have included in the below snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
        <input id="bet" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1"   onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
        <input id="submit_bet" type="submit" value="Submit Bet!"/>
    </form>

    <span id="range">0</span>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showValue(newValue)
    {
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
    }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submit_bet").click(function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
                $("#bet").hide();
                $("#submit_bet").hide();
                $("#range").hide();
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but in the snippet i don't see the slider coming back?

Comment: Same with me, but when I run the code locally it is not working for some reason.

Comment: did you use #range?

Comment: Yes, I definitely did

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: I guess you need to add jquery as a local file because cdn files won't load unless you use a web server

Comment: i have updated the code,the problem seems to be because of the form ,so when the button is clicked the fields are hidden and then the form is submitted thus refreshing the page and that is why the fields appear again so i have introduced the event parameter and then prevented the default submit behaviour by giving event.preventDefault()